# PHP version on windows is a ghost :o

Tags: php, windows, path, command-line-interface, version

Hi and thk for taking the time to read.

Situation :

- In my client [picture CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8B7Z.png)
- In my path [picture Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3usse.png)

First :

I am a beginner, I thought that "Windows" needed the path in "Path" to execute command lines.

So first question, why I have a version of php while normally not?

After :

And when I run WAMP[3.x], I still have the same version of PHP from the above capture.

Can someone explain to me?

Thank for read'n'time.

Comment: You don't need a path entry for PHP if you are running it in the same directory of the php executable. WAMP probably sets the path to PHP. What are you trying to accomplish? Is there an actual problem?

Comment: Several problems arise from its. Example of today, I can not install twig because of HTTP / HTTPS for the request. I noticed that when I move the "php5.3.9 /" from WAMP outside of its folder, I do not have an active php after a "php -v".
So I have a version of PHP from WAMP continuously even if I do not run it (still pathless in "Path" Win). How is possible ?

Comment: If this is an issue then you should simply add PHP to your path.

Comment: I already tried this, and putting the 7.x version of WAMP in the "Path Win" and it still shows me the 5.3.9 with "php -v".( And only one path for php, i know two can make conflit)

Comment: You need to read about how to set the Windows environmental variables, which includes the PATH variable.

Comment: ok thk for watching

Answer (score 0):

Problem halfe-solve :

I do not understand why, but when I do a "php -v" I have the version of my WAMP 2.2 (php5.3.9) instead of php7.1 from my Path Win.(WAMP disable)

So I leave the folder "php5.3.9" to place it in its parent folder.(next to "php/")

Now "php -v" return php7.1.

I feel like it's acting as if I had "php5.3.9" at the beginning of my Path Win. Except that no.

If I need to use a version of php included in WAMP 2.2, I move the folder "php5.3.9" in its original folder("php/"), because without it, it doesn't run.